# How to fill a dynamic Array with other dynamic arrays or values mixed?

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

Let's say you get a string of array-Dimensions from the Database. It would look something like this: `"[1][2][1]"` now you have a corresponding value, we shall call it B

I have to create an array of this format: `(x,(B))`

if another Value, we call it A had this Dimension-String: `[1][1]`, the array shall be filled like this: `(A,(B))`

and if by chance there is another Value named C with the String`[1][2][2]` the array is supposed to look like this: `(A,(B,C))`

i thought of something like :

```
Redim Array1(1)
Redim Array2(1)
Array1(0) = A
Array2(0) = B
Array2(1) = C
Array1(1) = Array2()
```

But that in a dynamic way. It seems to me, that vba does not support nested arrays.
Unfortunately a Multi-dimensional array will not work, as the "dimensions" are not consistent. any help appreciated

Edit: 
tried:

```
c = 0
dim array1() as Variant
redim preserve array1(c)
array1(c) = split(mid("[1][4]",2,len("[1][4]")-2),"][")
```

and it gave me a type mismatch error

Comment: In Access, the simple solution for an array is often a table.

Comment: sorry i can neither create nor change tables or databases, i am just supposed to return a text-file with values from db. i need to process all data i get to a human and machine-readable format that is preset. sorry but the whole rest is stuff that even i do not know

Comment: How about a disconnected record set? -- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184397

Comment: sorry but that will not help either. I need to keep the structure itself and have no fitting table for that. also i am currently working on a solution that should work, as soon as i can put the correspondng values in. thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Private Sub testArray()
  Dim DynamicArray1() As Variant
  Dim DynamicArray2() As Variant

  ReDim DynamicArray1(1)
  ReDim DynamicArray2(1)
  DynamicArray1(0) = "A"

  DynamicArray2(0) = "B"
  DynamicArray2(1) = "C"

  DynamicArray1(1) = DynamicArray2
End Sub

Sub test2()
  Dim c As Integer: c = 0
  Dim array1() As Variant
  ReDim Preserve array1(c)
  array1(c) = Split(Mid("[1][4]", 2, Len("[1][4]") - 2), "][")
End Sub
```

Comment: unforunately i do also not know how many arrays i will need. The string of dimensions could be almost anything. the first "Digit" will always be 1 but all the other things are "random"

Comment: yes it works, but i still have the problem, that the number of nested arrays is unknown and a nested array can nest another array

Answer (score 0):

You can nest arrays in VBA. You just have to make sure that the parent array is a variant array. Any "child" arrays can be of any type you want. In that case, the elements of the parent array will still be variant, but variants that happen to be arrays. Here is an example of how to use this:

```
Dim array1(1)
Dim array2(1 To 2) As String
array2(1) = "Hello"
array2(2) = "World"
array1(1) = array2
'Usage explanation:
'array1(1) returns the first element of parent array
'array1(1)(1) returns the first element of the returned element.
MsgBox array1(1)(1) & " " & array1(1)(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always collections/dictionary rather than array, they don't have to be typed and expand as required